# Visual Studio 2015 — autoresolve missing assemblies and usings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. I start writing code in C# as for example

```
MessageDialog msgBox = new MessageDialog("Message Goes Here");
```

and if in `using` part of code, If I have not written `Windows.UI.Popups` it will show me error. 
So in Visual Studio 2013 I use to right click and resolve Assembly so it will add code in using automatically.

But in VS 2015 I could not found that, But on the same time if I put cursor on the error and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> it will intellisense assembly add code into using part.

What setting I am missing in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: get Resharper to do it for you.

Comment: Do visual studio don't have feature by its own

Comment: it does. there is a light bulb at left side of line. this option was enabled for me by default. im not sure how to enable it though. but Resharper does not only provide you this feature. its real real powerful tool for .net IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS on its own is not able to resolve missing assemblies.
Here, you're probably missing `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

VS can only resolve missing `using`s.

As told in comments, ReSharper is able to also resolve assemblies.

Comment: I am looking for missing using only by right click, as I remember I had not installed resharp in VS 2013 but still that feature was working

Comment: Try to reference `System.Windows.Forms` in your porject, and you will see VS proposing you to autoresolve the missing `using` part. You probably  already had the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in VS2013.

Comment: but without putting `System.Windows.Forms` when I press **Ctrl + .** It shows me missing using part as intellisense

Comment: It's possible that Intellisense resolves system assemblies, but as far as I remember VS could not autoresolves `usings` of non imported assemblies (if so, they would appear as error).